# Does discretizing a diffusion model make it look like a jump diffusion model?

Tags: numerical-methods, jump-diffusion

Can we distinguish a sample generated from a diffusion model with large time steps from a sample generated from a jump diffusion model. Not mathematically but numerically (if we ask a computer to tell the difference) ?

Answer (score 2):

This not possible. The compensated Poisson process $N_t-\lambda t$ converges in the [limit](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24488/does-a-poisson-process-converge-to-an-ito-process-in-long-term) of large intensity $\lambda$ to a  Brownian motion with variance rate $\lambda\,.$ Therefore, the pure jump process $(N_t-\lambda t)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ converges to a standard Brownian motion. The consequence is: even if you give me discrete data that were simulated with a Brownian motion I could not rule out that they were generated by $(N_t-\lambda t)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ with a large enough $\lambda\,.$

Answer (score 1):

The principle is to assume some mathematical models (for example: the sample is generated from a log-normal process, or log-normal process with jumps, or CIR process, ...) and then estimate the parameters of these models.

Then we determine how well these assumed models fit the sample data. We need to choose a (or some) goodness of fit statistics for this evaluation (R-squared for example).

And by basing on the final statistics, we can guess which model may be the one that generated the sample data, in particular, whether the sample is generated from a jump diffusion model or not.